# ffmpeg droping session when there is no input , need to wait for an input

Tags: android, ffmpeg, live-streaming, android-ffmpeg

**I am trying to live stream to facebook from an application, which is writing frames into image sequence of XXX_Frame.jpg inside a folder.**

I am using a ffmpeg with these commands

*ffmpeg -y -r 15 -f image2 -start_number 0 -i "%0d_Frame.jpg" -i "test.mp3" -muxdelay 1 -preset slow -flush_packets 1 -ar 44100 -b:a 128k -profile:v baseline -acodec aac -vf scale=1280x720 -vcodec libx264 -crf 15 -r 50 -pix_fmt yuvj420p -minrate 50k -maxrate 150k -bufsize 8192k  -g 1 -b:v 1200 -f flv "rtmp://live-api-s.facebook.com:80/rtmp/xxxxxx"*

It is starting to stream faster than 15 frames per second and whenever it finishes up streaming of the available frames it is killing the process and returning error.
It would be perfect if it was possible to slow down the mux's read from the input to frame rate speed.

*[flv @ 000001f34347cf00] Failed to update header with correct duration.
[flv @ 000001f34347cf00] Failed to update header with correct filesize.
Error writing trailer of rtmp://live-api-s.facebook.com:80/rtmp/xxxxxx: Error number -10053 occurred*

Any help would be appreciated.

Expected result is to stream continuously without losing the connection , even sending the last available image continuously.

Comment: not sure I follow but you're probably looking for the rate emulation flag (`-re`) to simulate a live stream

Comment: @aergistal when I am using the _-re_ the sitution is not changing in the way that I need , It is giving me output like this
_frame= 267 fps= 12 q=22.0 size= 13250kB time=00:00:21.08 bitrate=5148.3kbits/s speed=0.951x frame= 273 fps= 12 q=22.0 size= 13613kB time=00:00:21.64 bitrate=5153.2kbits/s speed=0.954x_
and again after streaming some seconds dropping the session and returning
 _av_interleaved_write_frame(): Unknown error [flv @ 0000024a8d34e660] Failed to update header with correct duration. [flv @ 0000024a8d34e660] Failed to update header with correct filesize_